# Prove formally that $\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}}$ converges to $N(0,1)$ in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

It is known that
$$\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}}}$$
converges to $N(0,1)$ in distribution. However, I'm not able to prove that
$$\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}}$$
converges as well to $N(0,1)$ in distribution.

**My attempt:** we know that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{p}-p)\to N(0,p(1-p))$. I tried to find a function $g$ to apply the Delta Method, that is
$$\sqrt{n}\big(g(\hat{p})-g(p)\big)\to N\big(0,g'(p)^2p(1-p)\big).$$
However, it is not clear to me if it is possible to find such function $g$. On the other hand, the fact that $\text{E}\hat{p}=p$ seems to helpful, but I don't know how to apply it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the answer just after writing the question! Since $\hat{p}\to p$ in distribution, it follows that $$\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}\to\sqrt{p(1-p)}$$
in distribution. Finally, by [Slutsky's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) we have that
$$\frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}}\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}}}\to \frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}N(0,1)=N(0,1).$$